# Form Validation & Ajax Call on Same Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a button on which form gets submitted, I wanted to fire jquery Validation first and check if form is valid or not.
I tried doing this below but nothing works, even nothing gets showed in console.

HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $url;?>" id="add_group" class="add_group">
    <!-- My other fields-->
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JQuery
AJAX Call:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        formSubmit();
    });
function formSubmit()
    {
        var group_url = "{{ url('admin/groups/add') }}";
        var redirect_group_url = "{{ url('admin/groups') }}";
        var token = $('#token').val();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },

            url: group_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#add_group").serialize(),            
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status == 'failed' || data.status == false)
                {
                    $('.alert-danger').show();
                    $('.alert-danger').html(data.message);
                } else 
                {                    
                    window.location.href = redirect_group_url;
                    /*$('.alert-success').show();
                    $('.alert-success').html(data.message);*/                    
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {                
                $('.alert-danger').show();
                $('.alert-danger span.show_error_msg').html(data.message);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function() { $(".alert").hide(); }, 3000);
    }
```

My Jquery Validation Which I kept on document.ready function

```
$('.add_group').on('click','#submit', function(){
        //var $this = $(this);
        $("#add_group").validate({
            rules: {
                group_title: {   
                    required: true,
                }, 

                group_id:{
                    required: true,
                },
            },       
            messages: {

                group_title: {
                    required: "Please enter group title",
                },

                group_id:{
                    required: "Please choose group",
                },
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var attr_name = element.attr('name');
                error.insertAfter(element);            
            }
        });

        });
```

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Does  `$("#add_group").validate({..})` has any return value ?

Comment: Not it is not returning anything

Comment: @BitsPlease Why don't you use type="submit" instead of "button"

Comment: @Kirit I thought giving a try bt I have a ajax call so

Comment: @BitsPlease hope this will help you: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#add_group').submit(function(){
          $("#add_group").validate({
            rules: {
                group_title: {   
                    required: true,
                }, 

                group_id:{
                    required: true,
                },
            },       
            messages: {

                group_title: {
                    required: "Please enter group title",
                },

                group_id:{
                    required: "Please choose group",
                },
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var attr_name = element.attr('name');
                error.insertAfter(element);            
            }
        });

        });
    });
```

//Try this as it is but change button type to submit